# `const viewCommon={ ...components }` reports Syntax Error in WebStorm

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, webstorm

I use WebStorm open the colleague's Vue.js project:

There I get a Syntax Error:

```
error  in ./src/common/index.js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (24:1)

  22 | 
  23 | const viewCommon={
> 24 |  ...components
     |  ^
  25 | }
  26 | const install = function(Vue) {
```

As all we know, the `...` just is syntactic sugar in there.

In my WebStorm -> Preference -> Language & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> JavaScript language version, I have changed to the `EcmaScript 6`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ArStah, in the `build/webpack.base.conf.js` I add the `options: { presets: ['stage-2'] }` in the config:

```
 {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')],
    options: { presets: ['stage-2'] }  // before there is no stage-2.
  },
```

Then solved this issue.